# How do I upload my app to a Windows Phone 7 for testing?

Tags: windows-phone-7, file-upload

I'm developing an app for Windows Phone 7 mobile device.  I've finished testing with the emulator and now I want to test on an actual phone.  Does anyone know how I can upload the app to my phone?

I know that iPhone has a direct upload, Blackberry can install from any website.

How do I do this with Windows Phone 7?

Answer (score 3):

1. Register your phone as a developer device using your link - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff769508(v=VS.92).aspx
2. If you're writing in Visual Studio, then choose Windows Phone 7 Device as the target instead of Emulator
3. If you've just got a XAP file (from the bin/debug or bin/release directory) then you can use the "Application Deployment" tool.